# app in TestFlight crashes if compiled with Xcode 13.5.1 but works if compiled with Xcode 10.3

Tags: ios, xcode, crash

Getting this crash and I'm unable to find the cause.

The app is in testflight and is compiled with Xcode 13.5.1.

It is mixed Objective-c and Swift.

Crashes immediately and seems even to not enter Appdelegate.

The same app compiled with Xcode 10.3 and downloaded from testflight works perfectly.

Works when executed in both Xcode 13.5.1 and Xcode 10.3

```
{"app_cohort":"2|date=1592407800000&sf=143450&tid=3ad7fff33af6e11a89f32b7a1ba44b6729e557a7e7d872f0c5656bdbddaca6ed&ttype=i","app_name":"AppGolf","app_version":"1.99","timestamp":"2020-06-17 17:45:40.00 +0200","slice_uuid":"fde6c956-2d19-3c15-936a-3cccf74edc6e","adam_id":945626343,"build_version":"24","bundleID":"net.edisoftweb.ModenaGolf","share_with_app_devs":1,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 13.5.1 (17F80)","incident_id":"592037EF-0808-484A-8945-18CA99D5E976","name":"AppGolf","is_beta":1}
Incident Identifier: 592037EF-0808-484A-8945-18CA99D5E976
Beta Identifier:     96D9F66C-E982-493E-AA3E-E714192A0BE2
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,8
Process:             AppGolf [3366]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3CB71C90-9FE9-4526-9777-8DDC86269E66/AppGolf.app/AppGolf
Identifier:          net.edisoftweb.ModenaGolf
Version:             24 (1.99)
AppStoreTools:       11E608a
AppVariant:          1:iPhone11,8:13
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           net.edisoftweb.ModenaGolf [2171]


Date/Time:           2020-06-17 17:45:39.8379 +0200
Launch Time:         2020-06-17 17:45:39.1565 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.5.1 (17F80)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    2.06.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1a3288300 __exceptionPreprocess + 228
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1a2f9cc1c objc_exception_throw + 59
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1a3177e68 +[NSException raise:format:] + 111
3   UIKitCore                       0x1a6d15440 -[UISearchDisplayController initWithCoder:] + 87
4   UIFoundation                    0x1a68ecbcc UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 727
5   UIFoundation                    0x1a68ecfb8 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1731
6   UIFoundation                    0x1a6887fe0 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 311
7   UIKitCore                       0x1a6d5e0dc -[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 979
8   UIKitCore                       0x1a6d54230 -[UITableViewController initWithCoder:] + 67
9   UIKitCore                       0x1a704adbc -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 2367
10  UIFoundation                    0x1a68ecbcc UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 727
11  UIFoundation                    0x1a68ecdec UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1271
12  UIFoundation                    0x1a6887fe0 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 311
13  UIKitCore                       0x1a704a0ac -[NSCoder+ 7241900 (UIIBDependencyInjectionInternal) _decodeObjectsAndTrackChildViewControllerIndexWithParent:forKey:] + 319
14  UIKitCore                       0x1a6d5e2d4 -[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 1483
15  UIKitCore                       0x1a6cb9314 -[UINavigationController initWithCoder:] + 75
16  UIKitCore                       0x1a704adbc -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 2367
17  UIFoundation                    0x1a68ecbcc UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 727
18  UIFoundation                    0x1a68ecdec UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1271
19  UIFoundation                    0x1a6887fe0 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 311
20  UIKitCore                       0x1a704a0ac -[NSCoder+ 7241900 (UIIBDependencyInjectionInternal) _decodeObjectsAndTrackChildViewControllerIndexWithParent:forKey:] + 319
21  UIKitCore                       0x1a6d5e2d4 -[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 1483
22  UIKitCore                       0x1a6c9cabc -[UITabBarController initWithCoder:] + 83
23  UIKitCore                       0x1a704adbc -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 2367
24  UIFoundation                    0x1a68ecbcc UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 727
25  UIFoundation                    0x1a6887fe0 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 311
26  UIKitCore                       0x1a704eec0 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 131
27  UIFoundation                    0x1a68ecbcc UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 727
28  UIFoundation                    0x1a68ecdec UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1271
29  UIFoundation                    0x1a6887fe0 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 311
30  UIKitCore                       0x1a7049e90 -[NSCoder+ 7241360 (UIIBDependencyInjectionInternal) _decodeObjectsWithSourceSegueTemplate:creator:sender:forKey:] + 491
31  UIKitCore                       0x1a704ca58 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1067
32  UIKitCore                       0x1a753e9c4 -[UIStoryboard __reallyInstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:creator:storyboardSegueTemplate:sender:] + 283
33  UIKitCore                       0x1a753e85c -[UIStoryboard _instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:creator:storyboardSegueTemplate:sender:] + 127
34  UIKitCore                       0x1a73d0390 -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 183
35  UIKitCore                       0x1a73d08fc -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 275
36  UIKitCore                       0x1a73cf068 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1003
37  UIKitCore                       0x1a6b3f03c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 151
38  UIKitCore                       0x1a700ad68 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 111
39  UIKitCore                       0x1a6b3fb70 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 211
40  UIKitCore                       0x1a6b3f59c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 295
41  UIKitCore                       0x1a6b3f98c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 755
42  UIKitCore                       0x1a6b3f214 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 339
43  UIKitCore                       0x1a6b43930 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke_2 + 195
44  UIKitCore                       0x1a6f29604 +[BSAnimationSettings+ 6059524 (UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 855
45  UIKitCore                       0x1a7024a0c _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 259
46  UIKitCore                       0x1a6b4366c __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 155
47  UIKitCore                       0x1a70248f4 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 107
48  UIKitCore                       0x1a6b434c4 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 391
49  UIKitCore                       0x1a69a9ba4 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 639
50  UIKitCore                       0x1a69a86a4 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 255
51  UIKitCore                       0x1a69a98d4 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 235
52  UIKitCore                       0x1a73cd3fc -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 551
53  UIKitCore                       0x1a6f4fe08 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 375
54  FrontBoardServices              0x1a84eaffc -[FBSSceneImpl _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 439
55  FrontBoardServices              0x1a85115a0 __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.168 + 115
56  FrontBoardServices              0x1a84f5ebc -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 239
57  FrontBoardServices              0x1a8511234 __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 343
58  libdispatch.dylib               0x1a2f2833c _dispatch_client_callout + 19
59  libdispatch.dylib               0x1a2f2b0d4 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 263
60  FrontBoardServices              0x1a85376c4 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 47
61  FrontBoardServices              0x1a8537370 -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible] + 431
62  FrontBoardServices              0x1a85378dc -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 31
63  CoreFoundation                  0x1a3203af4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 27
64  CoreFoundation                  0x1a3203a48 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 83
65  CoreFoundation                  0x1a3203198 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 195
66  CoreFoundation                  0x1a31fdf38 __CFRunLoopRun + 795
67  CoreFoundation                  0x1a31fd8f4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 479
68  GraphicsServices                0x1ad614604 GSEventRunModal + 163
69  UIKitCore                       0x1a73d1358 UIApplicationMain + 1943
70  AppGolf                         0x102ec5f30 0x102e6c000 + 368432
71  libdyld.dylib                   0x1a30792dc start + 3


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a306edf0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a2f8e930 pthread_kill + 228
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001a2f1cba4 abort + 104
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a3041f40 __cxxabiv1::__aligned_malloc_with_fallback+ 65344 (unsigned long) + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a30338c8 demangling_unexpected_handler+ 6344 () + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a2f9cf0c _objc_terminate+ 24332 () + 132
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a30413cc std::__terminate(void (*)+ 62412 ()) + 20
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a3041358 std::terminate+ 62296 () + 44
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a2f28350 _dispatch_client_callout + 40
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a2f2b0d4 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 264
10  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a85376c4 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 48
11  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a8537370 -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible] + 432
12  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a85378dc -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 32
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3203af4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3203a48 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 84
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3203198 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 196
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a31fdf38 __CFRunLoopRun + 796
17  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a31fd8f4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480
18  GraphicsServices                0x00000001ad614604 GSEventRunModal + 164
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a73d1358 UIApplicationMain + 1944
20  AppGolf                         0x0000000102ec5f30 0x102e6c000 + 368432
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001a30792dc start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a2f959c0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a2f959c0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a2f959c0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a2f959c0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a304c784 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a304bba8 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3203314 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a31fe0a0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1156
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a31fd8f4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480
5   Foundation                      0x00000001a3546b18 -[NSRunLoop+ 31512 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a35469f0 -[NSRunLoop+ 31216 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a7477840 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 156
8   Foundation                      0x00000001a3680c10 __NSThread__start__ + 864
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a2f8d8fc _pthread_start + 168
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a2f959d4 thread_start + 8

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a2f959c0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x000000016cf91f40   x5: 0x000000016cf924f0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000500
    x8: 0x00000000000005b9   x9: 0x52edbf591e01e407  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x0000000000000003
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000050  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000001e500e808  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000407  x21: 0x0000000103285960  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000103285960
   x24: 0x0000000000002303  x25: 0x0000000000000001  x26: 0x000000016cf92cc0  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x00000001ee0b8000   fp: 0x000000016cf92450   lr: 0x00000001a2f8e930
    sp: 0x000000016cf92430   pc: 0x00000001a306edf0 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
0x102e6c000 - 0x102eeffff AppGolf arm64  <fde6c9562d193c15936a3cccf74edc6e> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/3CB71C90-9FE9-4526-9777-8DDC86269E66/AppGolf.app/AppGolf
0x103204000 - 0x10320ffff libobjc-trampolines.dylib arm64e  <7fd5d790e34f3b9e91a253f8e9428e91> /usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
0x103214000 - 0x10327bfff dyld arm64e  <3d545c044e25313eb748ef45647088f7> /usr/lib/dyld
0x1a2e5a000 - 0x1a2e70fff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64e  <a97807ab182135b5bec8f26659c6cc07> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x1a2e71000 - 0x1a2ea4fff libxpc.dylib arm64e  <33b9156a9ae13385bd0838552a3f3b7f> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution!
I used UISearchDisplayController that was deprecated.

console:
UISearchDisplayController is no longer supported when using this version of iOS. Please migrate your application to UISearchController.